# Перечисления "enum class"

Tags: c++, c++11, enum

Новый стандарт С++ дает возможность использовать новый тип перечислений, лично для меня это намного удобнее старых обычных `enum` "перечислений", но есть одна проблема - она очень не удобна лично для меня, вот пример и суть проблемы:

```
enum class Colors: DWORD
{
    RED = 0xFFFF0000,
    GREEN = 0xFF00FF00
    ...
}
```

Начинаю использовать:

```
void draw2DBox(DWORD col)
{
    ...//Не важно что здесь
}

int main()
{
    draw2DBox(Colors::RED )//Компилятор считает Colors::RED как какой-то объект а не член типа DWORD
    return 0;
}
```

Приходится делать приведение типов:

```
int main()
{
    draw2DBox((DWORD)Colors::RED )//Так компилируется - но это жутко не удобно
    return 0;
}
```

Может можно как-то обойтись без приведения типов?

**UPD:**

Использую VS 2015

Comment: @VladD - ах! забыл самое главное - использую VS 2015

Comment: @VladD, почему должно? Они же специально вводились, чтобы автоприведение НЕ работало.

Comment: `enum Colors : DWORD` будет работать. `enum class Colors : DWORD` - не будет. Почувствуйте разницу.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Тьфу, я прочитал условие как `void draw2DBox(Colors col)`.

Comment: @VladD, посмотрел историю - это было потом исправлено))

Comment: @VladD - ты правильно посмотрел - я просто не правильно написал, так как писал по памяти - я потом исправил!

Comment: Ах вот оно что :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Не работает, не должно работать и не будет работать.

Идеей введения `enum class` была изолированность его значений и видимость особого типа. Неявное приведение для него недоступно by design:

http://ideone.com/QQkRvZ

```
enum class test : int
{
    value = 0
};

int main()
{
    test t = 0;
    return test::value;
}
```

> ```
> prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
> prog.cpp:11:11: error: cannot convert 'int' to 'test' in initialization
>   test t = 0;
>            ^
> prog.cpp:12:15: error: cannot convert 'test' to 'int' in return
>   return test::value;
>                ^
> ```

Answer (score 19):

Запрет неявного приведения типа - это одно из следствий использования ключевого слова `class` в определении enum. Эффект этого ключевого слова двояк: во-первых, оно объявляет scoped enum (в отличие от "обычного" unscoped enum); во-вторых, оно запрещает неявное приведение к целочисленному типу.

В то же время в С++ вы можете "базировать" enum на выбранном вами целочисленном типе и без указания ключевого слова `class`

```
enum Colors : DWORD
{
  RED = 0xFFFF0000,
  GREEN = 0xFF00FF00
  ...
};
```

Вот такой enum-тип будет свободно приводится к целочисленному типу неявно, именно так как вы хотели.

Однако, убрав слово `class`, вы вместе с ограничениями на приведения еще и сделаете свой enum unscoped, т.е. теперь константы изнутри enum будут видны в глобальном пространстве имен как `RED`, `GREEN` и т.п. Т.е. нет необходимости использовать `Colors::RED`, `Colors::GREEN`. Это не очень приятно, но это уж вам судить, устраивает вас такой вариант или нет.

(При этом при желании вы можете продолжать обращаться к этим идентификаторам используя квалифицированные имена - `Colors::RED`, `Colors::GREEN` и т.п. Эта возможность появилась в С++11 вообще для всех enum-типов. Но фактически это не более чем syntactic sugar: для всех enum-типов, объявленных без ключевого слова `class`, имена констант скопом вываливаются в охватывающее пространство имен.)

Если же вам все таки очень хочется пользоваться неявным приведением, но при этом получить полный аналог scoped enum, то требуемое поведение можно "эмулировать" при помощи обертки из `struct`

```
struct Colors {
  enum : DWORD
  {
    RED = 0xFFFF0000,
    GREEN = 0xFF00FF00
    ...
  };    
};
```

Comment: Я так не хотел, потому что в дальнейшем может возникнуть проблема с переопределением каких-либо функций и имен других переменных, я хотел именно enum class только без приведения типов, мне очень удобно вызывать класс перечисления и в нем выбирать члены

Comment: @Duracell: Тогда просто заключите свой enum в namespace или struct и все дела.

Comment: Я так уже сделал) спасибо!

Comment: IMHO, namespace будет гораздо уместнее, чем struct.

Comment: @val: Где как... Преимуществом `struct` в качестве оболочки иногда является то, что `struct`-тип можно передавать в шаблоны в качестве аргумента. Актуальна ли это возможность в данном случае - вопрос отдельный...

Answer (score 9):

> Может можно как - то обойтись без приведения типов?

Можно. Но для этого придется либо изменить сигнатуру вызываемой функции с

```
void draw2DBox(DWORD col);
```

на

```
void draw2DBox(Colors col);
```

Либо добавить соответствующую перегрузку, которая внутри будет делать необходимое преобразование:

```
void draw2DBox(Colors col) {
    draw2DBox(static_cast<DWORD>(col));
}
```